# Instagram API error Client request limit reached

Tags: php, api, instagram

To make auomatically like photos on Instagram, I'm using cron job set to execute every 5 minutes. I make a call to a post just after new media was added.

Now that I have 350 request per access token per hour, calculating each 5 minutes, I will have 12 requests.

But I always get

```
stdClass Object ( [error_type] => APIError [code] => 400 
                  [error_message] => Client request limit reached )
```

How can I reset the number of requests to 0?

Comment: You've made too many requests to their API.  You probably can only make so many in a period of time.  You're probably just gonna have to wait.  While you wait, I suggest you check the docs for more info.

Comment: If you're given 350 requests, and your job runs once every 5 minutes, you're going to run into issues if you make more than 29 Instagram requests per job. (To gather posts is one request. To like a post is one request. It adds up quickly.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your client id is blocked for period of time because of the excessive requests.

Try to minimize the total per Hour to 30 likes only and check the system for one day.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909878/can-we-get-an-official-instagram-response-to-error-400-when-liking-photos)

BTW, i'm facing the same problem :(